# Unable to load my own components -angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, systemjs

I was unable to load component that was located at 'app/shared/lookup/lookup.component.ts' from 'app/associate/abc.component.ts'

**My folder structure**

[image: My folder structure]

**Error**
[image: Error]

**tsconfig**

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "bower_components",
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**Here is my System Config**

```
/**
       * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
       * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
       */
      (function (global) {

        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        var map = {
          'app': 'dist',

          '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
          'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
          'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
          '@vaadin': 'node_modules/@vaadin',
          'moment': 'node_modules/moment'
        };

        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        var packages = {
          app: {
            main: 'main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
          'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
          '@vaadin/angular2-polymer': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
          'moment': { main: 'moment', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        };

        var ngPackageNames = [
          'common',
          'compiler',
          'core',
          'http',
          'platform-browser',
          'platform-browser-dynamic',
          'router',
          'router-deprecated',
          'upgrade',
        ];

        // Individual files (~300 requests):
        function packIndex(pkgName) {
          packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
        }
        // Bundled (~40 requests):
        function packUmd(pkgName) {
          packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
        }

        // No umd for router yet
        packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

        // Forms not on rc yet
        packages['@angular/forms'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };


        // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
        var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
        // Add package entries for angular packages
        ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

        var config = {
          paths: {
            'app/*': './dist/*'
          },
          map: map,
          packages: packages
        };

        System.config(config);

      })(this);
```

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "sg-associate-portal",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "This is an application for SenecaGlobal",
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "*",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@vaadin/angular2-polymer": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "pace": "0.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "sweetalert2": "*",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Help me!

**I have observed that app was unable to load components outside the folder.
i.e.,
If component 'A' is located in folder '1' of root
component 'B' is located in folder '2' of root; app is unable to load component B from component A.
It is always trying to search the components with respect to current folder only.**

Comment: Could you also post the contents of `app/associate/abc.component.ts`? It seems that you are loading something from `associates/shared/lookup`, which doesn't exist (the `shared` folder is not located in `associates`).

Comment: **Yes, exactly that's where its going wrong.**
`
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PolymerElement } from '@vaadin/angular2-polymer';
import { AssociateService } from './associate.service';
import { LookupComponent } from '../shared/lookup/lookup.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'prospective-associate',
    directives: [LookupComponent, PolymerElement('vaadin-grid'), PolymerElement('iron-icon')],
    templateUrl: './app/associates/prospective.associate.component.html',
    providers:[AssociateService]
})
export class ProspectiveAssociateComponent {}
`

Answer (score 0):

The error message you attached says it is looking for the lookup component in dist/**associates**/shared/lookup/lookup.component.ts.

I think your import for the lookup component in 'app/associate/abc.component.ts' is incorrect...

Comment: dist is output folder mentioned in tsconfig.

systemjs loads app from dist

Comment: This is how I import lookup 

import { IFilter } from '../shared/search-fi‌​lter/searchfilter.com‌​ponent'; import { LookupComponent } from '../shared/lookup/lo‌​okup.component'; declare var Polymer: any; @Component({ selector: 'prospective-associa‌​te', directives: [LookupComponent, PolymerElement('vaad‌​in-grid'), PolymerElement('iron‌​-icon')], templateUrl: './app/associates/pr‌​ospective.associate.c‌​omponent.html', //stylesUrl: ['./app/assets/css/g‌​rid.css'] providers:[Associate‌​Service] }) 


there were no compile time errors. Runtime it failed to load the module.

Answer (score 0):

On the question - you are probably missing out on a traversal. i.e.  "../"

Second, These errors should show up at compile time. If you do not have a strong reason to use lite-server, use webpack for development - will significantly reduce your time debugging such errors along with other benefits

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Comment: This is how I import lookup

`import { IFilter } from '../shared/search-filter/searchfilter.component';
import { LookupComponent } from '../shared/lookup/lookup.component';
declare var Polymer: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'prospective-associate',
    directives: [LookupComponent, PolymerElement('vaadin-grid'), PolymerElement('iron-icon')],
    templateUrl: './app/associates/prospective.associate.component.html',
    //stylesUrl: ['./app/assets/css/grid.css']
    providers:[AssociateService]
})`

there were no compile time errors. Runtime it failed to load the module.